# tap on icon starts google maps activity but route is not displayed

Tags: android, navigation, maps, routes

I want to display route between two points (markers) and I pass to uri the strings of lat and long of the marker(endpoint). The second point is the gps position and I pass to uri its attributes too.
I have this android code In onClick method. When I first click a marker the route is displayed fine. When I exit google maps with back button (pressed twice) and tap immediately again a marker the route is not displayed, but if a little time has passed from the back button pressed (around 8 seconds) the route is displayed normally.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+s1+","+s2+"&daddr="+s3+","+s4;
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(uri));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    startActivity(intent);                  
}
```

Comment: Your question needs a little cleanup; it is confusing.  Your subordinate clause's subject is odd: "When I exit google maps with back button (pressed twice) and tap immediately again a marker the route is not displayed".  What do you mean by "a marker the route"?   Did you mean "a marker *on* the route?"  Just "a marker"?  Just "the route"?  Also, you could use "the" in a few places.